# Hpw to put 3 tables in one row im MPDF

Tags: html, css, mpdf

Does any one know how to display 3 tables in a row in mpdf generated page. Code example:

```
<htmlpagefooter name="custom-footer">
    <table width="250"><tr><td>First table</td></tr></table>
    <table width="250"><tr><td>Second table</td></tr></table>
    <table width="250"><tr><td>Third page</td></tr></table>
</htmlpagefooter>
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<htmlpagefooter name="custom-footer" class="flex">
    <table width="250"><tr><td>First table</td></tr></table>
    <table width="250"><tr><td>Second table</td></tr></table>
    <table width="250"><tr><td>Third page</td></tr></table>
</htmlpagefooter>
```

Comment: Yes, but MPDF plugin does'nt support flex =(

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

```
<htmlpagefooter name="custom-footer" class="footer-table">
  <table><tr><td>First table</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Second table</td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td>Third page</td></tr></table>
</htmlpagefooter>

.footer-table table{
   float: left;
   width: 33.33333333%;
 }
```